# Display GridView with many columns as two sets of columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-structures

I apologize for the odd title. I've been trying to figure out how to do this and can't quite put it into words. Basically, I need to try to display a GridView with a whole bunch of columns (37 in one case) in two "rows" of columns. More or less.

So instead of this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data    Data
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data    Data
Data    Data    Data    Data    Data    Data
```

I'd like something like this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
Data    Data    Data
Data    Data    Data
Data    Data    Data

Column4 Column5 Column6
Data    Data    Data
Data    Data    Data
Data    Data    Data
```

As in the example there can be multiple rows returned which all need to be displayed. I'm trying to stop a very large horizontal scroll bar being required. I've been searching as much as I can but haven't found anything that fits what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use 2 gridviews. I'd fetch the data in the code behind and cache it in a datatable. I'd then make 2 dataviews - the 1st one taking the 1st 3 columns; the 2nd one showing the last 3 columns. And then pass dataview1 to gridview1 and dataview2 to gridview2 and databind.

alternatively,

If you are simply worried that the page might overflow with horizontal scrolling, put the gridview in a div tag with style overflow scroll

```
<div style="overflow:scroll; width:95%">
<!-- gridview goes here -->
</div>
```